# I keep receiving error in R when I try to parse the JSON column in my dataframe

Tags: r, json

https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset
I am trying to do EDA on the metamoviedataset. I am very new to R and I have two questions:
How do I convert the char to numeric? any other option beside as.numeric?
How do I parse the JSON column? There are a few of them such as genre, production_companies,...
I used the following code but it kept giving me error.

```
Data = movies

m_genres=movies %>% filter(nchar(genres)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(genres,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,genre=name)%>%group_by(title)%>%mutate(pos = 1:n())%>%ungroup()

m_production_companies=movies %>% filter(nchar(production_companies)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(production_companies,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,production_company=name)%>%group_by(title)%>%mutate(pos = 1:n())%>%ungroup()
```

The errors I got:

```
lexical error: invalid char in json text
Error in fromJSON(content, handler default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object not found "json"
```

Then I tried running it this way:

```
genredf=movie %>% filter(nchar(genres)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(genres,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,genre=name)
slice(genredf)
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'name' not found
```

I have been working on this forever and couldn't get it to work. Please help.

My goal is something like the photo. 
Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUKdw.png)